# How to get .js and .css files and replace them

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress plugin.

I've created the basis for this and all is correctly set up.

I've tried looking at [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_header) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_footer) to see if I could request and get all of the scripts (.js files) from the header and footer.

I thought that was the best function but the result is not happening right.

I basically want to **get** the JS and CSS files and replace with another string.

So let's say this is my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.example.com/mycss.css" />
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/another_script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My function has to look for the .css and .js files and replace the string with other stuff. So that the result would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <mytag>Here was contained a CSS from http://www.example.com/mycss.css</mytag>
</head>
<body>

<mytag>Here were contained 2 JS from http://www.example.com/myscript.js and http://www.example.com/another_script.js</mytag>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
I actually have to get the name and path for those files.

I think I can use a regexp but I don't know how to load it using `get_header` and `get_footer` (if those are the right functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the enqueued script and styles by using `$wp_scripts` and `$wp_styles` global variables.

See the class reference for [WP_Styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Styles) and [WP_Scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_scripts/) for available methods and properties.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I need to get the path and file name for each. See my edit please.

Comment: I guess you could work with the `print_code` property, use the `reset()` method to clear the `WP_Styles` instance then re-enqueue the styles.

Comment: George answer seems more appropriate - use his code to change the file name and path, and enqueue the styles / scripts again.

Answer (score 3):

It would make much more sense, rather than removing the relevant markup after receiving it from `get_header()` and `get_footer()` functions, to dequeue all styles and/or scripts so they are never printed there in the first place.

You can get the path for the file by looking back at the `$wp_styles`/`$wp_scripts` objects' `registered` property. You can then go on to get the filename using [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
function dequeue_all_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;

    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ){
        wp_dequeue_style($handle);
        $src = $wp_styles->registered[$handle]->src;
        $filename = basename($src);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_all_styles', 100 );

function dequeue_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ){
        wp_dequeue_script($handle);
        $src = $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
        $filename = basename($src);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_all_scripts', 100 );
```

If you have *other* styles and scripts to put in their place, simply use `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I need to get the path and file name for each. See my edit please.

Comment: Fantastic!!! What if, instead of writing back the scripts with the enqueque function, I want t write custom text in the same spot?